# Install/Enable/Activate plugin on multisite without access to master site

Tags: plugins, multisite

I have inherited a WP multisite without the access to the main site (network admin). I need to install a plugin and have unpacked it via FTP but need to enable it and can't. Any way of doing this via MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an option in the wp_sitemeta table with meta_key 'menu_items'

[image]

this value is referred to the checkbox "Administration menu" of the page /wp-admin/network/settings.php (accessible only to siteadmins) that allows the activation of plugins on single sites. 
[image]

I've not tested but using the value `a:1:{s:7:"plugins";s:1:"1";}` and having the plugin uploaded via ftp you should see the plugin page on the site you've access to..

Comment: @kaperto @andrea I don't have the `_sitemeta` table?
 http://prntscr.com/kd9tln

Comment: quite weird ..(?) https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Multisite_Table_Overview

Comment: you're looking into a paginate sidebar of tables? I see wp_14 as prefix in your screenshot

Comment: looking at some other installs I have from Softaculous, the don't have that table either (basic WP installs, not even multisite)

Comment: _sitemeta is specific for multisite you will not find in a standard installation

Comment: I think it's just the corrupt setup. No problem, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL acces, you can change your account privileges to become a super-admin.

To do that, got to the table `..._sitemeta` and add your username to the option `site_admins`. It's a serialized array then if you have already a user `admin`, you will put something like `a:2:{i:0;s:5:"admin";i:1;s:5:"sixli";}`.

look the manual for https://secure.php.net/serialize

Comment: of course this answer @Kaperto is  much stronger , I would say "resolutive"!! lol, mine is less intrusive

Comment: thanks @Kaperto - any ideas on why I don't have the _sitemap table?